# Web API upload file then process and download file in one web API request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have looked through the posts on here and throughout Google and can't seem to find a solution to this.

I want to do this without using Node.js if I can. If I cannot then I will do it because it is required.

I know how to upload a file such as:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostEncryption()
    {
      var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
      //do some editing on the file
    }
```

And I know how to download a file via get

```
private HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        var txtString= "a bunch of random stuff";
        var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StringContent(txtString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/txt");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "test.txt"
        };

        return result;
    }
```

What I am trying to do is pull a file in then do some processing and force the download of the file in the browser. Is this possible through the web API and if so, how would I accomplish it?

Here is my code currently as asked for by slaks, at this point i am just trying to get a post method to download a file...

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
var txtString= "a bunch of random stuff";
        var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new StringContent(txtString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/txt");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "test.txt"
        };

        return result;
    }


$('#uploadFile').on('click', function () {

            var data = new FormData();

            var files = $("#file").get(0).files;

            // Add the uploaded content to the form data collection
            if (files.length > 0) {
                data.append("file", files[0]);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/apifile/post",
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data
            });
        });
```

Comment: You can return any result you want from any action; you can combine those two examples.

Comment: I tried that and the file never downloads, but if i just use the get it downloads just fine.

Comment: What do you see in the Network tab? How are you making the request? Show us your code.

Comment: Ok so reading up i found that I cannot use ajax to download a file, is this correct? How can i get around this?

Comment: Don't use AJAX.  Make a form submit instead.

Comment: @SLaks omg, I was just making it more difficult then it had to be. Thank you man